# How to get parameter names in grails starts with given string?

Tags: grails

How to get params with names like in grails ?
ie. id_1, id_2 . . . etc. Is there anything like params.['id_*'] in groovy or grails?

Comment: I suggest to use something like id.1, id.2 in the params and access them as params.id.<parameter name>
:)

Comment: where you able to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 5):

To get the list of ids for example starting with `"id_"` you can do this:

```
def map=[id_1:1,id_2:2,max:1,offset:2]
def fparms=map.findAll{it.key.startsWith("id_")}
assert fparms==[id_1:1, id_2:2]
```